Force two typescript objects to have same keys
I want to use a nested object as keys for translations.
Say
interface TranslationObject {
  [key: string]: string | TranslationObject
}

An instance of the object would be like:
const en = {
   MAIN_MENU: {
       TITLE: 'Welcome'
   }
...
}

I have another variable es, with the same keys. Is there a way to enforce this at type level?
I could of course write:
interface MyTranslation = {
   MAIN_MENU: {
       TITLE: string
  }
}
const es: MyTranslation = ...

But that's not what I want, I want something that it is automatic and requires no maintenance. Something like:
const es: InferTheType(b) = ...


You could use typeof on en to give you a shape for the other ones, maybe as shown in this playground link. Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz wow, so simple

I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Luckily, the type you want for MyTranslation is precisely the type that TypeScript infers for en when you initialize it with an object literal.  The keys of all properties and nested properties are known, while string literals like 'Welcome' get widened to string.  That means you can just use the type level typeof operator on en to get the desired type for MyTranslation:
const en = {
  MAIN_MENU: {
    TITLE: 'Welcome'
  }    
};

type MyTranslation = typeof en;
/* type MyTranslation = {
    MAIN_MENU: {
        TITLE: string;
    };
} */

Once you do that, your subsequent values will behave as desired. You'll need to specify the same keys in the object and nested properties, but the actual string values can be anything you want:
const es: MyTranslation = {
  MAIN_MENU: {
    TITLE: 'Bienvenido'
  }
}

Things get more complicated if type inference doesn't keep track of what you want exactly, and there are approaches you can take there (usually involving a generic helper function) but that's out of scope for the question as asked.
Playground link to code

const en = {
    MAIN_MENU: {
        TITLE: 'Welcome'
    }
...
}

interface MyTranslation {
    [key in keyof typeof en]: {
        TITLE: string
    }
}

This might fit
